# How can i build conditions through widgets when streaming data?

Tags: flutter, text, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm streaming a collection as snapshot from a firestore to my flutter project. How can i write inside a text widget e.g. 'empty' when the variable im looping doesn't exist in the collection?

```
child: Column(     
    children: <Widget>[
      if (title != null)
        {
          Text(
            title,
            ),
          ),
        }
      else {
        Text('empty'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below code:-

```
String title = '';
return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title.isNotEmpty ? title : 'empty')
        ],
      ),
);
```